# URL Rewriting and 301 Redirect... Redirects to the original URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http-status-code-301, url-rewriting

In answering another persons question here on SO, I discovered that there is a small "bug" in my global redirect code.

I have wired up a Global class to an HttpModule.  It's job is to detect "http:/www." in the URL and redirect the user to the NON www. version

```
Protected Sub OnBeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Force Removal of WWW
    Dim application As HttpApplication = TryCast(sender, HttpApplication)
    Dim url As Uri = application.Context.Request.Url
    Dim hasWWW As Boolean = If(url.ToString.StartsWith("http://www."), True, False) 'UrlRegex.IsMatch(url.ToString())
    If hasWWW Then
        Dim newUrl As [String] = UrlRegex.Replace(url.ToString(), [String].Format("{0}://", url.Scheme))
        application.Context.Response.Redirect(newUrl, False)
        application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 301
        application.Context.Response.End()

    End If

End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that when it redirect a page `http://www.example.com/AboutUs`, the goal is to have it go to `http://example.com/AboutUs` (the rewritten page) but instead it's going to `http://example.com/Default.aspx?Slug=AboutUs` (the original page).

I tried doing a bit of a hack by changing

```
    Dim newUrl As [String] = UrlRegex.Replace(url.ToString(), [String].Format("{0}://", url.Scheme))
    application.Context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
    application.Context.Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl.Replace("Default.aspx", ""))
```

to

```
    Dim newUrl As [String] = UrlRegex.Replace(url.ToString(), [String].Format("{0}://", url.Scheme))
    newUrl = newUrl.Replace("Default.aspx?Slug=", "")
    newUrl = newUrl.Replace("Default.aspx", "")
    application.Context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
    application.Context.Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl)
```

not something I want to do anyways since it's a hack, but it didn't work anyways.

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer that works

```
    Protected Sub OnBeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'Force Removal of WWW
        Dim application As HttpApplication = TryCast(sender, HttpApplication)
        Dim url As Uri = application.Context.Request.Url
        Dim hasWWW As Boolean = If(url.ToString.StartsWith(String.Format("{0}://www.", url.Scheme)), True, False)
        Dim forceWWW As Boolean = Boolean.TryParse(ICMS.Site.Settings.GetSettingsValue("ForceWWW"), False)
        'UrlRegex.IsMatch(url.ToString())
        If hasWWW Then
            Dim newUrl As String = UrlRegex.Replace(url.ToString(), String.Format("{0}://", url.Scheme))
            application.Context.Response.Redirect(newUrl.Replace("Default.aspx?Slug=", String.Empty), False)
            application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 301
            application.Context.Response.End()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
application.Context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
application.Context.Response.AddHeader("Location", newUrl)
```

Try this:

```
application.Context.Response.Redirect(newUrl, false)
application.Context.Response.StatusCode = 301
application.Context.Response.End()
```

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - You have a test page so I can see the headers it's sending?

Comment: rockinthesixstring  - Can you give me a page under there that *should* be redirecting me?

Comment: every navigation link is rewritten. So if you click on "Contact Us", the link is http://staging.infinitas.ws:83/Contact-Us ... If you manually append the WWW. in front of it and then press [enter], you'll see the incorrect address (http://staging.infinitas.ws:83/Default.aspx?Slug=Contact-Us)

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - Still can't test...since your global script checks that the url starts with www, I tried: http://www.infinitas.ws/Contact-Us, http://www.staging.infinitas.ws/Contact-Us, each on port 80 and 83...is the problem that since your redirect code is wrapped inside `If hasWWW Then`, it won't run on staging?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to access it remotely, I'll have to do it when I get back to the office.

Comment: Ok you should be able to try now.  The primary url is `http://www.cms.infinitas.ws`

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - Can you post current code?  The response doesn't make any sense, newUrl is coming out just as you say...is the last block in your question the current code?

Comment: the current code is the first block exactly.  The last block was simply something I "tried" that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use IIS and setup a defferent website.  Do a permanent redirect, preserving the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Request.RawUrl, e.g.

```
Dim newUrl As [String] = UrlRegex.Replace(Request.RawUrl.ToString(), [String].Format("{0}://", url.Scheme))
```

Request.RawUrl should be the original URL from the actual http request.